# Pass JSON string to function with angular2

Tags: angular

I want to be able to change the color between green and red when an ion-item is clicked.

The code below retrieves multiple names and colors from a JSON string and it works.

```html
  <ion-item *ngFor="let data of data" [style.backgroundColor]="data?.color" (click)="PostData(data)">
    {{data?.name}}
  </ion-item>
```

But the problem starts when I want to pass the data back to a function so I can use the PUT method to send the new data back to the API I got the JSON string from.

```js
PostData(data) {
    var url = 'http://www.external.tld/page/'+data?.id;  // append the id to the url
    if (data?.color == 'red') {data?.color = 'green'};
    if (data?.color == 'green') {data?.color = 'red'};   // toggle color
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'});
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    return this.http.put(url, JSON.stringify({"name": new String(data?.name), "color": new String(data?.color)}), options)
    .map(res => res.json());    // send name and toggled color
}
```

I am a noob with angular 2 so I have no idea what I am doing right and wrong.

Bonus: I also didn't get the PUT method to work yet (I even prefer to send the data (name and color) without JSON if possible).

Comment: Please,specify what the problem is. Also, `data?.id` isn't valid Typescript.

Comment: In the html i am using data?.color and data?.name to get the current index of all names and colors. I want to use that same data in the ts file, but I dont know how.

Comment: To say it easier: if I click the second item with the name test and color red. Then I want to retrieve only that name and color in the ts file, toggle the color to green and send the name and color with a working put function.

Comment: @torazaburo It is in the body of PostData method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: You shouldn't name both variables of your `*ngFor` the same!

```html
<ion-item *ngFor="let d of data" [style.backgroundColor]="d?.color" (click)="PostData(d)">
  {{d?.name}}
</ion-item>
```

Second: `?.` isn't valid Typescript, as @estus already mentioned.
Yes, of course in your angular2 template its valid!

But in Typescript you have to check if its defined:

```js
PostData(data) {
    if (!data) return; // its null or not defined.. get out of here .. !

    var url = 'http://www.external.tld/page/'+data.id;  // append the id to the url
    if (data.color == 'red') {data.color = 'green'};
    if (data.color == 'green') {data.color = 'red'};   // toggle color
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'});
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    return this.http
       // USE x-www-form-urlenoded instead of JSON
       .put(url, `name=${new String(data.name)}&color=${new String(data.color)}`, options)
       .map(res => res.json());    // send name and toggled color
}
```

Comment: Thank you so very much! This saved me a lot more brainpain!

Comment: Can you please help me with the bonus question? I can't make the http.put function to work (I want to send name and color to my api). I prefer it to do it without json. I got it to work in postman by setting the name and color in the body with application/x-www-form-urlencoded.

Comment: You have to set the `body` of your put-request like this `name=YOURNAME&color=YOURCOLOR`. See my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I still cannot send the data. Am I missing something? The link is correct, the content-type is correct, name and color are being sent as x-www-form-urlencoded. Why won't it work :( Even when I hardcode the data.

Comment: A slight thing I noticed in postman is that it not only sends x-www-form as a header, but it's also an option in the body tab, next to form-data, raw and binary. I have no clue how to deal with this info, hope you can help me out :)

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop is incorrect. You bind to a data array, and let the value at each index equal the variable/letiable "data". My guess is, on click, your data variable is not the iterated value, but the entire array of data. Console log data from your PostData() method.

```
*ngFor="d of data" [style.backgroundColor]="data.color" (click)="PostData(data)"
```